# Can't recompile xmonad because of newer GHC version

Tags: apt, xmonad

I get this message when running `xmonad --recompile`

```
xmonad.hs:10:8:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad’
    Perhaps you meant
      Monad (needs flag -package haskell98-2.0.0.3)
      DsMonad (needs flag -package ghc-7.8.4)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

xmonad.hs:14:18:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.StackSet’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Please check the file for errors.
```

Well, really when I run `ghc xmonad.hs` in `~/.xmonad`, but the messages are the same except this one doesn't give weird output for some characters. Right now I suspect that the problem is with my current GHC version, which I think is different from when I last ran `xmonad --recompile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed GHC 7.8.4 some time ago by installing from source - I needed a more recent version than what I could manage to get with apt-get. I also had GHC version 7.4.3 or something like that installed, which seemed to *shadow* my newer GHC. So I uninstalled that version using using apt-get. So perhaps the problem is that the command `xmonad --recompile` tries to use the `ghc` command, which now is the newer GHC? I have used GHC to recompile my configuration file before, and at that time I probably used the `apt-get` installed GHC.

Let's try to see what happens if I install xmonad.

```
my-machine:~$ sudo apt-get remove xmonad
[...]
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,654 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

Only ~2.5 MB to remove.

Now let's try and reinstall.

```
my-machine:~$ sudo apt-get install xmonad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
ghc ghc-doc ghc-haddock libghc-mtl-dev libghc-mtl-doc libghc-random-dev libghc-syb-dev libghc-transformers-dev libghc-transformers-doc libghc-utf8-string-dev libghc-x11-dev
libghc-x11-doc libghc-x11-xft-dev libghc-x11-xft-doc libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev libghc-xmonad-contrib-doc libghc-xmonad-dev libghc-xmonad-doc
Suggested packages:
ghc-prof haskell-doc llvm-3.0 libghc-mtl-prof libghc-random-doc libghc-random-prof libghc-syb-doc libghc-syb-prof libghc-transformers-prof libghc-utf8-string-doc
libghc-utf8-string-prof libghc-x11-prof libghc-x11-xft-prof libghc-xmonad-contrib-prof libghc-xmonad-prof
The following NEW packages will be installed:
ghc ghc-doc ghc-haddock libghc-mtl-dev libghc-mtl-doc libghc-random-dev libghc-syb-dev libghc-transformers-dev libghc-transformers-doc libghc-utf8-string-dev libghc-x11-dev
libghc-x11-doc libghc-x11-xft-dev libghc-x11-xft-doc libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev libghc-xmonad-contrib-doc libghc-xmonad-dev libghc-xmonad-doc xmonad
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/66.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 428 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

A lot of `*ghc*` dependencies, and a requirement for 428 MB compared to only freeing ~2.5 MB when uninstalling xmonad.

Now `ghc` points to the ghc installed by apt-get, as indicated by runnnig `ghc --version`

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

And now `xmonad --recompile` works.